# Recursive definition of sequences inverse/equivalency.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

So here's the problem:

"Give a recursive definition of the sequence ($a_n$), $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ if $a_n = 4n - 2$."

Here's my answer:$$t_1 = 2; t_n = t_{n-1} + 4$$

However, I know this could also be the answer:$$a_1 = 2; a_{n+1} = a_n + 4 \text{ for all }n \ge 2$$

Is my answer incorrect or does it not matter which order I put them in? Thanks!

Comment: Both answers are equivalent. Note that for the first one you also need to state $n\ge2$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks man!

Comment: And for the second one you nee to state $n\geq 1$ and not $n\geq 2$